# GC overhead limit exceeded while runing liquibase generateChangelog

Tags: maven, liquibase

I am new to liquibase and started using it to export data from oracle db. I am getting "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". Found few SO threads where it was suggested to increase heap size. I did that as well but in vain. The command I am trying to run is

mvn -X liquibase:generateChangeLog -Dliquibase.diffTypes=data

Here is my pom.xml:

```
  <project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mytests.liquibase</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-liquibase</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
          <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                  <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
                  <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
          </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx2048m</argLine>
                <propertyFile>
                        C:/Users/ygupta/Tools/db/liquibase.properties
                </propertyFile>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is liquibase.properties file:

```
driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//nssrXXXX:1521/com
changelogSchemaName=XX
defaultSchemaName=XX
username=CXX
password=password
outputChangeLogFile=C:/Users/ygupta/Tools/db/dbcalms.changelog.xml
```

Is there anything else I can try to mitigate heap/GC issues here?

Answer (score 0):

OOME could be either lake of heap memory, either lake of RAM memory.

with the command top (linux) or system manager (windows), you could see if your system is running enough central memory or swap space.

Another way to solve your problem, is how did you specified heap size to your command line ?

Comment: export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx10096m -Xms10096m -Xmn50m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=64m  -verbose:gc -Xloggc:./gc.log -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC  -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15  -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=./heap_dump -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps"

Comment: to size the Maven heap size, yes ! (10GB is perhaps a bit to large)